# express.js chain routes in any order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I'm making an API in express that has many endpoints, a few examples:

```
product/colour/:COLOUR
product/brand/:BRAND
product/size/:SIZE
product/gender/:GENDER
```

The thing is, I want the user to be able to chain such endpoints in whichever order they please, for example one user may type this endpoint:

```
product/size/:SIZE/colour/:COLOUR/gender/:GENDER/
```

but another user may type

```
product/gender/:GENDER/size/:SIZE/colour/:COLOUR
```

Is there a way to do this without creating hundreds upon hundreds of routes for each possible combination?

Thanks in advance,
Ant

Answer (score 1):

may be query string is suitable for this case.

```
/product?colour=red&size=xl&gender=male
```

Comment: I thought as much, was just hoping there would be a more SEO friendly way.

Answer (score -1):

all your defined routers will be not matched.

You can use this route to match all you need,

```
product/:key1/:value1/:key2/:value2/:key3/:value3
```

and then you can use 'if' to check your key/value pair at controller path

Comment: The only issue with this method is that the user would have to send the exact amount of keys/values right? For example they couldn't just grab /brand/:BRAND/size/:SIZE with this route?

Comment: yes, if you want dynamic inputs, my suggestion does not cover that need